# Как написать прописью дробь?

Tags: числительные, недопустимая-метка

Как написать прописью дробь `20/12354`?

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, тут будет "двадцать двенадцать тысяч триста пятьдесят четвертых". Но такие дроби прописью не пишут из-за их громоздкости.